# making a question app and need help rendering question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a quiz app and after the first question loads i cant seem  to figure out how to get the next questions to load. And the then how to score it when they get it right or wrong. Any help would be great appreciated.

```
let questions = [
 {
  question : "how many stages are in the tour de france?",
   options : [
     {
    option : "2"
    },
    { 
    option : "10"
    },
    {
    option : "15"
    },
    { 
      option : "21"
     }
  ],
  answer : "D"
 },
  {
  question : "how many guys are on each team?",
  options : [
    {
     option :"9"
     },
    { 
    option : "10"
    },
    {
    option : "8"
    },
    { 
    option : "7"
    }
  ],
  answer : "A"
 },
 {
   question : "how many times did Lance Armstrong win the tour?",
  options : [
   {
    option :"7"
     },
   { 
      option : "4"
    },
    {
      option : "2"
    },
    { 
      option : "9"
    }
  ],
  answer : "A"
},
{
   question : "who won in 2018?",
  options : [
    {
      option :"Garrent Thomas"
    },
    { 
      option : "Chris Froome"
    },
    {
      option : "Peter Sagan"
     },
    { 
      option : "Taylor Phinney"
    }
   ],
  answer : "A"
  },
 {
    question : "what team won the tour in 2017",
  options : [
    {
    option :"Movistar"
  },
  { 
    option : "Bora"
  },
  {
    option : "sky"
  },
  { 
    option : "dropac"
  }
  ],
   answer : "c"
 },
```

];

```
 let currentQuestion =0;

 let score = 0;






/* $('input[name=option]:checked').val() */


function renderQuestion(){

    return `
      <fieldset>
    <legend> ${questions[currentQuestion].question} </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="A">${questions[currentQuestion].options[0].option}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="B">${questions[currentQuestion].options[1].option}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="C">${questions[currentQuestion].options[2].option}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="D">${questions[currentQuestion].options[3].option}<br>
    <button type="submit" class="submitAnswer"> Submit answer </button>
   </fieldset>

   `;
    }





  function startQuiz(){
    $('.quizAppForm').on('click', '.startQuiz', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

    $('.quizAppForm').html(renderQuestion);
  });

}



function init(){
 startQuiz();
 renderQuestion();


 $(init);
```

ive been stuck on this for a few days and its really driving me nuts. i am new to coding. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Call the init function like this: init(); and add a closing curly brace after you setup the init function. You missed one.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert this string into an array of objects and at each step you could retrieve the information of the current object

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining the content each time there is an answer you could change your renderQuestion function to this:

```
function renderQuestion() {

    document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML =
    `
    <fieldset>
    <legend> ${questions[currentQuestion].question} </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="A">${questions[currentQuestion].options[0].option}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="B">${questions[currentQuestion].options[1].option}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="C">${questions[currentQuestion].options[2].option}<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" 
    value="D">${questions[currentQuestion].options[3].option}<br>
    <button id="button" class="submitAnswer"> Submit answer </button>
    </fieldset>
   `;

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        let hasAnswer = false;

        for (let el of document.querySelectorAll("input")) {

            if (el.checked) {

                hasAnswer = true;

                if (el.value === questions[currentQuestion].answer) {

                    score++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasAnswer) {

            if (currentQuestion === questions.length - 1) {

                document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = `Your score is ${score}`;
            }

            else {
                currentQuestion++;
                renderQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And check for a valid answer every time someone clicks the button. Since for every question you create a new button, you have to register the event listener on each render. Alternatively you could render once the button and after each answer only the question and options and define the listener once. Hope this helps.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/869ponrf/